# Adjust Width of Jupyter Terminal

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I start a Terminal from the Jupyter homepage (New>Terminal) it's opening with a width of 40 characters. Can this be adjusted? This started happening after I updated `custom.css` with `.container { width:100% !important; }` to allow notebook cells to expand to full browser width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Jupyter `4.4.0` terminal width conforms to `.container { width:100% !important; }` in `custom.css` and expands as expected.

Answer (score 0):

My Jupyter 4.4.0 worked on Chrome only after I put the following in file .jupyter/custom/custom.css.

```
# the note book page
.notebook_app .container {
    width:98%; !important
}
# the terminal page
.terminal-app .container {
    width:98%; !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jupiter core version 4.6.0, following did not work

```
.terminal-app .container {
    width:98%; !important
}
```

but following worked.

```
.terminal-app #terminado-container {
    width: 98%;
}
```